# What exactly does packing with pkcs -certfile do?

Tags: openssl, strongswan

I've been using the openssl `pkcs12` command to pack my certs/keys up for Windows 8,

```
openssl pkcs12 -export         \
    -in win8client-cert.pem    \
    -inkey win8client-key.pem  \
    -certfile ca-cert.pem      \
    -out win8client.p12
```

However, I'm not entirely clear what it does. If I'm feeding it the `-certfile` why is that the certfile must also be manually installed on the host machine (a Windows 8 box)? When I take the `.p12` and extract the cacert (using the Certificates MMC on Windows) I can install it on the host box and everything works fine.

Why can't it just get the CA cert form the `.p12` (which is just a packing format by my understanding).

Answer (score 6):

The Certificates MMC, when importing a PKCS#12 file, puts all certificates in the *Personal/Certificates* folder, even the CA certificate. The problem is that CA certificates have to be located in the *Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates* folder to be actually used as root in a certificate chain verification. Therefore, if you manually move the certificate to that folder after importing the PKCS#12 container everything should work as expected.